# Link 2 Entities not populating partial class properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am working on a project to list automobiles.  I am using linq to entities. I have a table listing and a corresponding class Listing in my data model.

```
Listing 
{
Listingid,
AccountID,
MakeId,
ModelId
}
```

I have lookup table where I keep all the lookup values for makes and models..

```
Lookupvalues
{
id,
Description
}
```

I haven't created a join between these tables yet.

In a display page I have to display all the corresponding values from the lookup tables for makes and models.  How should I fetch them?  I have written a partial Listing class and created all these descripiton properties:

```
public partial class Listing
{
MakeDescription
ModelDescription
}
```

I wrote stored procedure which joins the tables but it doesn't load the description properties in the partial class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ADO.NET Entity Framework Extensions](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions), this should help.

---

Devart Team 
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect 
ADO.NET data providers for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite with
Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL support

Answer (score 0):

> I havent created join between these tables yet.

There is your problem. You should model this as associatons between `Listing` and `LookupValues`. Once you do that, you won't need your partial class anymore, as you can just project out what you need for display:

```
from l in Context.Listings
select new 
{
    Listingid = l.Listingid,
    AccountID = l.AccountID,
    MakeDescription = l.Make.Description,
    ModelDescription = l.Model.Description
}
```